# Create Login via SqlCommand - Parameters Not Substituted

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core

I am trying to create a new SQL login on via c#. I have tried the following to set the query params:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlServerConnString))
{
    connection.Open();

    string addLogin = "CREATE LOGIN [@databaseUserId] WITH PASSWORD = '@databasePassword';";
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(addLogin, connection))
    {
        // Attempt 1.
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@databaseUserId", databaseUserId);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@databasePassword", databasePassword);

        // Attempt 2.
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@databaseUserId", databaseUserId));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@databasePassword", databasePassword));

        // Attempt 3.
        command.Parameters.Add("databaseUserId", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = databaseUserId;
        command.Parameters.Add("databasePassword", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = databasePassword;

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Each "Attempt" was run individually.

No matter which version I try, the command completes without error. However, when I check the logins on SQL Server, I can see that it has created a user with name "@databaseUserId".

I can confirm that the databaseUserId and databasePassword variables are both non-null.

What am I missing?

Comment: Close connection adter you run sql each times

Comment: You shouldnt need the ' marks round the password

Comment: Just guessing, but have you tried `string addLogin = "CREATE LOGIN [@databaseUserId] WITH PASSWORD = @databasePassword;";` without the quotes around the password? Isn't the point of using parameters is so that it'll do the quoting for you?

Comment: You can't use a variable to replace a string literal. The above would try to create a login with the name `@databaseUserId` **not** the *value* of `@databaseUserId`.

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a C# developer, so I'm *trusting* that the code you have is correct.

As I state in my comment *"You can't use a variable to replace a string literal. The above would try to create a login with the name `@databaseUserId` **not** the value of `@databaseUserId`."* It would also set the password of that login to be the string `'@databasePassword'` (again, not the value of `@databasePassword`).

You'll need to use dynamic SQL to achieve this within your statement. I *believe* this will work, but I have no way of testing.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlServerConnString))
{
    connection.Open();

    //string addLogin = "CREATE LOGIN [@databaseUserId] WITH PASSWORD = '@databasePassword';";
    string addLogin = "DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@databaseUserId) + N' WITH PASSWORD = N' + QUOTENAME(@databasePassword,'''') + N';'; EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;";
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(addLogin, connection))
    {

        command.Parameters.Add("databaseUserId", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar,128).Value = databaseUserId;
        command.Parameters.Add("databasePassword", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar,128).Value = databasePassword;

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Note the **important** use of `QUOTENAME` here, and that the SQL you call is still parametrised on the application side of things. As you need to use literal strings for the values, you have to inject them (which is *normally* frowned upon). `QUOTENAME` **properly** quotes your strings meaning that the exposure to injection is significantly reduced (some as simple of this now will be injection "immune").

So, if someone did try to inject with the login name then the characters would be escaped. For example the value `N'L] WITH PASSWORD = 'abc123!"£'; ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER L;--'` the value would be be quoted to the value `[L]] WITH PASSWORD = 'abc123!"£'; ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER L;--]`, and a login with that (stupid) name would actually be created (provided a value password was supplied). For the password, as it needs to be a string literal, rather than a literal, I use the 2nd parameter, to tell SQL Server what character to quote the string with.

Comment: This seems to be the correct approach. I would use the same with `PHP` for `CREATE LOGIN` statement.