# Pass parameter to the SQL statement which is CREATE LOGIN type by JDBC PrepareStatement

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have a SQL statement `create login user_bob with password = ?;`. Trying to passing the real password to the statement by JDBC PrepareStatement. It should be executed without surprise. But unfortunately, got an error showing as "Incorrect syntax near '@P0'." Love to know the way to solve this.

My code looks like:

```java
String sql = "create login user_bob with password = ?;"
try (var conn = dataSource.getConnection()) {
    try (var stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        stmt.setString(1,  conf.getPwd());
        stmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Fail to create logins, already rollback, caused by:", e);
    }
}
```

The stack trace is:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:265)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1662)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:615)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:537)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7417)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3488)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:262)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:237)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:483)
```

Comment: You can't parametrise the `CREATE LOGIN` statement. You'd need to ***SAFELY*** inject the value as a literal `nvarchar`. One way would be use parameters, and `QUOTENAME` to make a dynamic statement and then execute the dynamic statement with `sys.sp_executesql`.

Comment: Though for C#, I demonstrate the same idea in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58198234/create-login-via-sqlcommand-parameters-not-substituted/58198422#58198422).

Comment: Yeah. Great!!!  Thank you,  Larnu. According to your method, I made it by changing the statement to ` exec ('create login ' + 'user_bob' + ' with password = ' + ?);`

Comment: That isn't **SAFELY** @FengLei ... There's a reason I emphasised **SAFELY**.

Comment: Imagine, for example, if someone passed their "password" as `1; ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER user_bob`.

Comment: Yes. That is enlightening. I can see the danger.  But I am not quite familiar with the syntax of a literal `nvarchar`.   How to write it correctly in a SQL file?

Comment: In Java 9 and higher, you can use [`Statement.enquoteNCharLiteral(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#enquoteNCharLiteral(java.lang.String)) to generate a correctly escaped N(VAR)CHAR literal for a string value (or [`enquoteLiteral(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#enquoteLiteral(java.lang.String)) for a normal string literal)